# htacces for github commit hook url

Tags: .htaccess, github

I am trying to make use of github's commit hook url.

I have added a url to a folder I am tring to hide from everyone except git hub via an htaccess file in the directory im trying to hide.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 50.57.128.197, sh2.rs.github.com, 108.171.174.178, sh3.rs.github.com
```

on my server i have the following error:

```
[error] [client 188.220.202.221] client denied by server configuration: xxx
```

Any thought on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i pointed github's commit url to a php file which triggered a git pull request.

Super simple and works well.